# How to have a drawer with 2 separate colors in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to figure out how to have the green fill up the entire drawer space under the yellow header. Right now I have my ListTiles wrapped in a Column, in a Container, with the Container color set to green. All help is appreciated.

[What I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9HqZ.png)

Comment: Please share your code to help better ,thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the ways could be wrapping the ListView that you are probably using with a Container that has color green. Please see the code below :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: HomePage());
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Flutter Demo"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      drawer: Container(
        color: Colors.green,
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            DrawerHeader(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
              child: Container(
                child: const Center(child: Text("Profile")),
                color: Colors.yellow,
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: const Text('Item 1'),
              tileColor: Colors.green,
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: const Text('Item 2'),
              tileColor: Colors.green,
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it was actually simpler than that. All I had to do was "drawer: Container()" instead of "drawer: Drawer()".

Comment: You are correct, I fixed the code and description as per your comment.